# Python. UnEscape. "\\x32" -> "2"

Tags: python, кодировка

Собственно нужно следующее:

```
>>> s = "\\144\\x65\\143\\x6f\\144\\x65"
>>> s_unesc = s.some_func()
>>> s_unesc
"decode"
```

Подскажите **some_func** ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> '\\144\\x65\\143\\x6f\\144\\x65'.decode('string_escape')
'decode'
```

Comment: Вот так да. Спасибо большое. Наградил.